# @StackAnime is a bot or a human being?

Tags: support

Checking the revisions history in any of my questions, I noted that appears when my question was tweeted by @StackAnime, and two things called my atention:

- One of the question appears tweeted two days after I wrote my question,
  but another 4 hours after.
- [One of the tweets](https://twitter.com/StackAnime/status/375050200668442624) shows exactly the title of my question, but [another
  tweet](https://twitter.com/StackAnime/status/375684453844398080) has "Can you answer this?" to the beginning.

All this makes me wonder if is someone who is tweeting the questions(I thought it was just a bot).

So, if is a human, is more than one? this is gonna be forever or is just gonna be while Anime & Manga is in beta?
In any case, what's the criteria to tweet a question? or all the questions are gonna be tweeted sonner or later?

Comment: I don't know the criteria, but it's definitely a bot. I'm not sure why it was tweeted more than once. As far as I know it's not supposed to do that, and I only see it being tweeted once in the revision history. This could be some sort of bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @StackAnime account is most definitely a bot. The specific inner workings of the bot has not been publicly disclosed.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94593/1288) there is a "hotness" algorithm based on views over a certain period of time.  Which is likely to be similar to the algorithm that populates the [recently active questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/) page.

In the same answer, it's been noted that questions have to have a score of >= 1 in order to be tweeted. There seems to be [another check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115899/1288) to avoid tweeting questions that have close votes, unless there is an active a bounty on it.

Comment: Just a [tiny bit more](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214/can-we-have-all-our-site-tweets-fall-under-the-b3d-hashtag) to add from a somewhat similar question.